# SQLLite QueryBuilder: "appendwhere" doesn't add "and"

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I thought "appendwhere" was supposed to handle the conversion of clauses to proper sql code. This is why I wrote the following:

```
                  if (match % 2 == 0) qBuilder.appendWhere("_id=" + uri.getLastPathSegment() + " ");

            if (hasRecordExistField) qBuilder.appendWhere(TableObject.FIELD_RECORD_EXISTS + "=" + Globals.DEFAULT_EXISTS + " ");
            c = qBuilder.query(
                    db,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
```

Yet, when I execute, both "appendwhere" clauses are simply concatenated. If "appendwhere" doesn't take care of adding " AND " in-between clauses, what purpose does it serve?

Here is error description:

> near "record_exists": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT
>   name FROM game WHERE (_id=0 record_exists=1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yet, when I execute, both "appendwhere" clauses are simply concatenated.

That is what the documentation says it does:

> The final WHERE clause looks like: `WHERE (<append chunk 1><append chunk2>) AND (<query() selection parameter>`)

In your case, your two pieces are `<append chunk 1>` and `<append chunk 2>`, respectively. The `AND` comes in with the `selection` parameter to the `buildQuery()` call.